# How to store and retrieve last used session of an Activity in Android Application

Tags: java, android, session

The android application having a toolbar with three buttons of three different implementations. The toolbar is common for all the activities. while for single click, these toolbars, should display their last used session/Activity and for double click they should display their initial or default states. Can anyone help me with samplecode/links on **how to store and retrieve last used session of an activity in android.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for persistent storage of screen , store requiered data as `SharedPreference`/`File`/`SQLite` . 
for cache or runTime storage use  `onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState)`

for default values , you can store these values in res/values and set them as hint/text whenever required  .